# Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different firebase react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm trying to automatically delete data older than 2 hours in the firebase real-time database, but after typing this code, it returns me a Malformed calls from JS:field sizes are different error.

```
function reloadDatas() {
  const ref = database().ref('messages/');

  const now = Date.now();
  const cutoff = now - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1 minute in milliseconds

  const old = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);

  old.once('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      childSnapshot.ref.remove();
    });
  });
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test your code but we can see the following error in the code: The `remove()` method is asynchronous so you cannot call it in a `forEach()` loop. One solution is to use `Promise.all()` in order to call it a variable number of times in parallel.

So, the following should do the trick (untested):

###### JS SDK v8

```
  old.get().then((snapshot) => {
    const promises = [];
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      promises.push(childSnapshot.ref.remove());
    });
    return Promise.all(promises)
  });
```

###### JS SDK v9

```
  get(old).then((snapshot) => {
    const promises = [];
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      promises.push(childSnapshot.ref.remove());
    });
    return Promise.all(promises)
  });
```

---

Another possibility would be to simultaneously write to the different database nodes with the `update()` method and passing `null`. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) in the doc form more details.

Comment: yes, that worked for me. Thank you very much. But when I run the code, it deletes all the data. I don't see any errors in the code. Could be why? i just want  to delete data that's older than 2 hours.

Comment: "I just want him to delete data that's older than 2 hours." That's a problem with the definition of `old` and `cuttoff`. You need to debug this part. Also, note that by using `Date.now();` you get the time of your computer which may be different from the time of the RTDB backend (e.g. different time zones). One recommended approach is to use a Cloud Function which executes in the backend.

Comment: In its current form, this answer leaves floating Promises because it is kicked off in an event callback rather than chaining to `old.once(...).then(...)`.

Comment: Hi @samthecodingman, good remark thanks, answer adapted.